# DirSource returning empty directory error despite correct file path

Tags: r, tm

This seems like a very basic issue. The file path is valid and I can open the file using other means in R, but I am looking to use `tm` library.

```
docs <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/xyz/Work/test.corpus.txt"), encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Throws an error of:

```
Error in inherits(x, "Source") : empty directory
```

**EDIT:**

This works with the original method:

```
docs <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/xyz/Work/"), encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Apparently you cannot specify an individual file name. The solution is to to read the file via another method and then use another source type such as VectorSource.

Comment: If you read the help, you can see that you can specify a pattern so that `DirSource` only picks the files with that pattern. `pattern = ".txt"` for all txt files. Or if you want, `pattern = "test.corpus.txt"` for only this file.

Comment: Not sure how this is a simple typographic error hold. There is zero examples of usage in the R help text that it can be used this way and this question has had similar questions asked dealing with the same problem, one without an answer and another where the user actually chose to go a different route.

Comment: @phiver Can you make the comment into an answer as I was able to get this to work. Want to give the credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a pattern so that `DirSource` only picks the files with that pattern. pattern = ".txt" for all txt files. Or if you want, pattern = "test.corpus.txt". Something like below.

```
docs <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/xyz/Work/", pattern = "test.corpus.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```